# Laravel error putting 2 controllers to the same route and i need it to show my data to the frontend(i divided it into 2 controller to clean my code)

Tags: php, laravel

Route::get(
'/',
[FrontendIntroController::class, 'index'],
[FrontendInfoController::class, 'index'],
)->name('intros.index','infos.index');

Comment: Why would you do such?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one route pointing to two different controllers. It's not possible in Laravel and besides that is poor code practice. Rather what you should do is point the route to one controller and handle the data accordingly, depending if it is `Intro` or `Info`.